# How to parse a string data from array inside JSON another array in Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, jsonparser

I have to show string data into a tableView.

```
{
"success": [
    [
        "An Ad with order id 2563 at location DLF, Delhi has been approved | 20 hours before|Shashank Tiwari"
    ],
    [
        "An Ad with order id 2539 at location V3S Mall has been approved | 1 week before|Shashank Tiwari"
    ],
    [
        "An Ad with order id 2515 at location Pacific Mall has been approved | 1 week before|Shashank Tiwari"
    ],
    [
        "An Ad with order id 2500 at location Ambience Mall has been rejected | 1 week before|Shashank Tiwari"
    ],
    [
        "An Ad with order id 2499 at location Vience Mall has been approved | 1 week before|Shashank Tiwari"
    ],
    [
        "An Ad with order id 2480 at location DLF, Delhi has been approved | 2 weeks before|Shashank Tiwari"
    ]
}
```

So I am parsing data as like below but not able to append data in to arrData Array.

```
           let json = try JSON(data:data
           let result = json["success"]                                           

                 print(result)


                    for arr in result.arrayValue {

                        self.arrData.compactMap{ $0 as? NSArray}
            }
```

Comment: Are you trying to append data by calling `compactMap`? what is arrData?

Comment: arrData is var arrData = [String]() its  an array variable

Comment: So what are you trying to do with `compactMap`?

Comment: I am trying to append data in arrData from arr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flatten the array then `compactMap` is the wrong API.

Use `reduce`

```
let result = json["success"]
let array = (result.arrayObject as! [[String]]).reduce([], +)
self.arrData.append(contentsOf: array)
```

- `arrayObject` returns `[Any]?`, you have to downcast it to the real type `[[String]]`
- `reduce` transforms the two-dimensional array to an one-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks Vadian, its working fantastic for me. Can you please elaborate it ??

Comment: (result.arrayObject as! [[String]]).reduce([], +)

Answer (score 0):

You can to it with another way like

```
let result = json["success"]
if let arr = result.arrayObject as? [[String]] {
    let array = arr.map { $0.first! }
    self.arrData.append(contentsOf: array)
}
```